# ActiveRecord 4.2 to 5.0.1 datetime precision behavior change

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to upgrade my project to [ActiveRecord 5.0.1](https://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord) with Mysql 5.6.33 and [mysql2 gem 0.4.5](https://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2). I have a number of spec tests that involve creating a record, then searching for records whose `created_at` value is `<= Time.now`. I have summarized the failure with the following example of a behavioral change from ActiveRecord 4.2 to ActiveRecord 5.0.1:

**ActiveRecord 4**

```
irb(main):021:0> puts Time.at(1482722443.8581448)
2016-12-26 03:20:43 +0000
=> nil
irb(main):022:0> p.updated_at = Time.at(1482722443.8581448)
=> 2016-12-26 03:20:43 +0000
irb(main):023:0> p.save
=> true
irb(main):024:0> p.updated_at
=> 2016-12-26 03:20:43 UTC
irb(main):025:0> p.reload
=> #<Profile id: 1, ...
irb(main):026:0> p.updated_at
=> 2016-12-26 03:20:43 UTC
```

**ActiveRecord 5.0.1**

```
> puts Time.at(1482722443.8581448)
2016-12-26 03:20:43 +0000
=> nil
> p.updated_at = Time.at(1482722443.8581448)
=> 2016-12-26 03:20:43 +0000
> p.save
=> true
> p.updated_at
=> 2016-12-26 03:20:43 UTC
> p.reload
=> #<Profile:0x0055e04486dc40
 id: 1,
 ...
> p.updated_at
=> 2016-12-26 03:20:44 UTC
```

As you can see, in the first example in AR4, the datetime returned by the database is at the 43-second mark, and it is therefore doing a `floor` operation on the supplied timestamp of `1482722443.8581448`.

In AR5, it is doing a `round` operation, and moving the `created_at` time to be the next whole second, thus making it go from second 43 to second 44.

This is causing records to be created "in the future", and my example of creating, then searching for records whose `created_at` is `<= Time.now` is returning no records because it has literally been created in the future by some millisecond-margin.

Is this behavior expected, or is this a bug? Can I configure this millisecond rounding behavior in AR5?

***UPDATE***

It looks like in mysql if I do:

`update alerts set created_at = '2016-12-26 04:08:19.7777' limit 1;`

And then:

`select created_at from alerts;`

I get

`2016-12-26 04:08:20`

Thus mysql is doing the "rounding up". Is it possible that, from 4.2 to 5.0.1, ActiveRecord starting writing queries with datetimes as

`2016-12-26 04:08:19.7777`

Instead of

`2016-12-26 04:08:19`

With Mysql 5.6.33?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ActiveRecord 5 has changed its behavior per [this blog post](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/23/rails-5-handles-datetime-with-better-precision.html).

Here are the [two](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/e975d7cd1a6cb177f914024ffec8dd9a6cdc4ba1) [commits](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/f1a0fa9e) that add this support in ActiveRecord 5.0.1.

To restore old behavior, I had to add the following monkeypatch:

```
module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    class AbstractMysqlAdapter < AbstractAdapter
    end
    class Mysql2Adapter < AbstractMysqlAdapter
      def supports_datetime_with_precision?
        false
      end
    end
  end
end
```